# Can i simulate using Kinect without having Kinect on jade?

Tags: gazebo, navigation, simulation, kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am fairly new to ROS and I use ROS Jade. I recently created a 4 wheel platform/robot (URDF model) and I wanted to put on it a Kinect Sensor so I can simulate the sensor in a custom environment via gazebo, before actually buying one. Is there a way to do that (it would be really helpful if you had some tutorial links) ? Or generally is there a way to simulate sensors in general without actually owning one ? I have checked openni, but I think this package helps you if you actually have the sensor.

Thanks for answering in advance and also thank you for your time.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239025/can-i-simulate-using-kinect-without-having-kinect-on-jade-?/) by [patrchri](https://answers.ros.org/users/26728/patrchri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 354 on 2016-07-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS by itself doesn't simulate things, but using a simulator, it is possible to do what you want: the simulator (or a plugin for it) should then 'sense' the simulated world and construct the appropriate ROS messages, so your ROS application receives the correct data.

Gazebo is one simulator for which this is possible. See [Tutorial: Using Gazebo plugins with ROS](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_gzplugins) for information on how to do that with various simulated sensors. A virtual depth camera is one of them (see [Openni Kinect](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_gzplugins#OpenniKinect)).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-07-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [patrchri](https://answers.ros.org/users/26728/patrchri/) on 2016-07-07**:
Will the results of the simulation be close to what I will actually get from the device itself when I try to experiment with it, from your experience?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-07-08**:
Well, the plugin models a 'generic' depth sensor, so I doubt it's going to be a 100% accurate model of a kinect. It's good enough to get similar data that you'd get from a real kinect.